# "JAVA" Нужно отправить get запрос и взять json

Tags: java, json, строки, get

Нужно отправить GET запрос, не принципиально как и взять с сервера ответ в виде JSON. Или можно просто из `stringbuffer` сделать JSON. Но как?

У меня ответ такой:

```
{"response":{"count":1,"parameters":[{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":"test","bogy":"messsage"}]}}
```

Нужно только значение `"4"`, то есть `test`

```
URL url = new URL(link);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью библиотеки [`Jackson`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode responseNode = rootNode.path("response");
JsonNode parametersNode = responseNode.path("parameters");
Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = parametersNode.elements();
JsonNode fourNode = null;
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    fourNode = iterator.next().path("4");
}
if (fourNode != null) {
    System.out.println(fourNode.textValue());
}
```